# How to get no. of elements with particular 'id' using robot framework?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, robotframework

I am writing an automation test script for our web application using Robot framework and Selenium2Library. One of my test case involves the following scenario.

I have to run a particular test case only if web page contains more than one `div` tag with a similar `id` !

Is there any specific keyword in robot framework to set the value of a variable as a count of html tags having same id's ?

Here is a similar html code am dealing with :

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <span>........</span>
</div>
<div id="dashboard">
    <span>........</span>
</div>
```

I have to store the total number of div tag's with `id=dashboard` in a variable `${Count}` .

Along with that , can we make use of Comparison/Relational operators directly in Robotframework test scipt ? 
i.e , can I write a test case similar to this :

```
Run Keyword If  ${Count} > 1  Found More Elements
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium2Library has a keyword named [Get Matching XPath Count](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Matching%20Xpath%20Count) which can return the number of items that match an xpath. The documentation even includes an example of counting items based on an id.

It would look something like this:

```
${Count}=    Get matching xpath count    //div[@id='dashboard']
```

> Along with that , can we make use of Comparison/Relational operators
>   directly in Robotframework test scipt ?

Yes you can, exactly like you showed in your question (assuming `Found More Elements` is a keyword):

```
Run Keyword If  ${Count} > 1  Found More Elements
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Selenium. You can use that to get a list of web elements with same attribute and then use it in your check.

```
List<WebElement> allelementwithsameid = driver.findElements(By.id("dashboard"));
```

Here you're using the `findElements( )` method to get all the elements, which have the id "dashboard".

Next, check if the length of the list is greater than zero.

```
if((allelemtwithsameid.size()> 0) {
  System.out.println("Size greater than zero. can use the element");
  count=allelementwithsameid;
 }

 else {
  //use some exception handling code here.
 }
```

Now, I don't have much knowledge of Robot plus Selenium, but I think you can use the `"count"` variable in your Robot framework's code.

> My Java coding skills are not the best. But I think you would get the idea.